# PHP: compare two arrays and sort by priority

Tags: php, sorting, comparison, multidimensional-array

I would like to compare two arrays: one is containing the list of possible options and the other array contains priorities.

This is how the two arrays are organized :

```
foreach ($varsA as $varA) {
  foreach ($varsB as $varB) {
      $options[$varA][$varB] = $id;
      $priority[$varA] = $priority + $priority[$varA];
    }
}
```

this is what $options contains:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    33307 => 'w',
    33313 => '7',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    33307 => 'w',
    33313 => '7',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    33307 => 'w',
    33313 => '7',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    33307 => '4',
    33313 => '7',
  ),
)
```

and this is what $priority contains:

```
array (
  1 => 5,
  2 => 9,
  3 => 9,
  4 => 5,
)
```

I would like to duplicate the duplicates values from $options and keep the one with the uniques with the lowest priority:

The output would be: `Array (1, 4)` Because 1, 2, 3 are not unique and 1 has the smallest priority.

I was using the following function to remove duplicates but I don't know how I can adapt it to deal with priorities:

```
super_magic($options) {
    $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $options)));
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
      if ( is_array($value) ) {
        $result[$key] = super_magic($value);
      }
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for ($x = 1; $x <= count($options); $x++) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= count($options); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($x, $options) && array_key_exists($i, $options)) {
      if ($x != $i) {
        $diff = array_diff($options[$x], $options[$i]);
        if(empty($diff)) {
          if ($priority[$x] >= $priority[$i]){
            unset($options[$x]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very specialized scenario without a foundation specific to PHP.  With that being said, i would look into http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php that page for specifics on the PHP functions at your disposal for using PHP arrays.  I would look into the functions like uksort() and uasort()